# Cant select AppIcon in Xcode

Tags: ios, flutter, xcode

I am trying to publish a app in Store but even if I get zero error when archive and deliver to appStore connect, cant see a build in appstore connect
I found something different in appIcon but not sure if its the problem
I cant choose appIcon and when I archive and deliver to app store, app's icon doesnt show up how can I fix it

Found this
[This is how it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2KJf.png)
But it seems like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyIBA.jpg)

and here my archive and store connect looks like
[Archive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z6ugF.jpg)
[store](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8KdW.jpg)

[build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XfbzE.jpg)

Comment: It's not the problem, please share app store connect screenshot..maybe it's there.

Comment: Can you share build number and etc. detail ss ?

Comment: Select `TestFlight` section on top of the AppStoreConnect site. What do you see here?

Comment: No builds shown @son

Comment: So weird, it often shows up here (with Pending status) after a few minutes. I think you should double-check everything like bundle id, etc.

Comment: It should show here after some time but if it's not showing up check your email, your app may require some permission strings ( add in info.plist)

Answer (score 0):

My experience with various submissions over the years, is that the build should show up as an entry very soon after you have successfully uploaded. (I've used only Xcode, but I'm sure the other methods have similar behavior).

The entry should appear in the web page with the correct version and build number.

Very early on, it might appear as "processing", with a wireframe/placeholder app icon.

Later, it will continue "processing", but with the app icon.

If you do not see it appear, and you have no errors from the local side of the submission, you should wait whatever you think is a reasonable interval, and then contact Apple if it doesn't appear. You can re-upload, or increment build number, to troubleshoot, but once you think it will not show, you should inform them.

I strongly recommend describing the critical details first, esp. whether this is the first build of a new app (or even a big re-write or change of build system) from previous builds. Or if it's the first build submitted over.

I've worked on maybe a dozen apps over the years (not to brag, but more to point out I've got some mileage...), and I've seen most of the obvious types of misbehavior... like:

1. Errors on the submission side that land without a problem.
2. Errors on the submission side that don't match errors on the service side.
3. Build simply never appears, or take a long time (hours/days?)
4. Build arrives, but icon never parsed (even though it was bundled in submission.
5. New builds never finished processing, apparently because I had changed the lineup of extensions, even though all the various extensions had been received successfully, before.

In short, the system works well, but not 100% of the time, and if a build submission is a problem, it is likely to be a problem you cannot resolve, but that someone on there service-side can.